# Трансляция видео,радио на сайт

Tags: трансляция

Имеется два стримера avermedia один транслирует на телевидение другой на радио
Нужно транслировать и на сайт.
Есть веб сервер на котором стоит сам сайт.
Медиа сервер для видео,радио каждому отдельный нужен или можно один сервер использовать?
Еще какие оборудования нужны?

Помогите пожалуйста а то я как ёжик в тумане...)
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все упирается в процессоры и каналы. Количество серверов прямо пропорционально количеству слушателей. Количество слушателей ограничено пропускной способностью канала, причем как по скорости, так и по количеству пакетов в секунду.

## Софт:

**Серверы отдачи контента:**

nginx-rtmp - прекрасный плагин к nginx. Авторская [статья](https://habrahabr.ru/post/162237/) о нем

icecast2 - умеет отдавать WebM, это значит, что работатет с мобильными браузерами

**Транскодеры:**

ffmpeg

gstreamer

**Плееры для браузера:**

Flowplayer - хорош тем, что поддерживает кучу форматов.

**Технологическая цепочка:**

транскодер - серверы отдачи - плеер.

Транскодер может быть один, он должен генерировать несколько форматов видео, которые затем можно Multicast-потоком пускать на серверы отдачи.